# why when AsyncTask execution the app always force stop?

Tags: android

why when `AsyncTask` execution the app always force stop?
There's have 2 result, first is if the AsyncTask `success access` the url that will force stop, and if `failed to access` the url will show the error and that not force stop.

this is my code:

```
private void insertToDatabase(final String alamat) {

   class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
       myProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
       myProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
       myProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
       myProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
       myProgressDialog.show();
     }

     @Override
     protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       String text = null;
       String urlATM = alamat;
       try {
         JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(urlATM));
         if(data.length()!=0){
           HashMap<String, String> map;

           for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
             JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
             map = new HashMap<String, String>();
             map.put("id_atm", c.getString("id_atm"));
             map.put("id_bank", c.getString("id_bank"));
             map.put("nama_bank", c.getString("nama_bank"));
             map.put("latitude", c.getString("latitude"));
             map.put("longitude", c.getString("longitude"));
             map.put("name", c.getString("name"));
             map.put("email", c.getString("email"));
             MyArrListATM.add(map);
             //end add marker

             maps.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title("ATM"+MyArrListATM.get(i)
                    .get("nama_bank"))
                    .snippet("24 Jam")
                    .position(new LatLng(
                           Double.parseDouble(MyArrListATM.get(i).get("latitude")),
                           Double.parseDouble(MyArrListATM.get(i).get("longitude")))));
           }
           myProgressDialog.dismiss();
         }
       } catch (JSONException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();

         text = e.getMessage();
       }
       //
       return text;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       super.onPostExecute(result);
       myProgressDialog.dismiss();

       AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
       alertDialog.setTitle("PERINGATAN");
       alertDialog.setMessage("Error: "+result);
       alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "TUTUP", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
          }
       });

       alertDialog.show();
     }
   }
   SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
   sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(alamat);
}
```

and the error showing to this code:

```
sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(alamat);
```

am I doing some wrong?

logcat:

```
07-15 15:33:53.196 19175-23224/com.emergency.e_place E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
                                                                       Process: com.emergency.e_place, PID: 19175
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on the main thread
                                                                           at maps.f.g.b(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at maps.z.F.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at maps.af.t.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at vl.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:167)
                                                                           at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.addMarker(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.emergency.e_place.MainActivity$1SendPostReqAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:584)
                                                                           at com.emergency.e_place.MainActivity$1SendPostReqAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:552)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
07-15 15:33:54.606 19175-19175/com.emergency.e_place E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.emergency.e_place.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41a95858 V.E..... R......D 0,0-471,144} that was originally added here
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:451)
                                                                          at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:267)
                                                                          at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
                                                                          at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:289)
                                                                          at com.emergency.e_place.MainActivity$1SendPostReqAsyncTask.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:559)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
                                                                          at com.emergency.e_place.MainActivity.insertToDatabase(MainActivity.java:629)
                                                                          at com.emergency.e_place.MainActivity.access$1000(MainActivity.java:77)
                                                                          at com.emergency.e_place.MainActivity$17.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:961)
                                                                          at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:136)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:153)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
                                                                          at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.onItemClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:187)
                                                                          at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:308)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1510)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3472)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4835)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please post the stacktrace

Comment: this could be because you access GoogleMaps when it's not connected yet. Try checking if before `maps.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()` your code still working or not.

Comment: myProgressDialog.dismiss(); remove this from background method and write it on post method. because only background task must be written here. all ui task must be written in post method and pre method as our condition.

Comment: By the way, using Volley or Retrofit would make getting that JSON easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map.addMarker`, `dismiss dialog` or any change in UI **must** done on the UI thread and

> doInBackground(Params...), invoked on the background thread

So you should remove `myProgressDialog.dismiss();` in your `doInBackground` 
and move `maps.addMarker...` to `onPostExecute(Result)` or `onProgressUpdate(Progress...)` (because `onPostExecute` and `onProgressUpdate` invoked on the UI thread)

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
   ...
   //end add marker
   MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().title()....;
   onProgressUpdate(markerOptions)
}
protected void onProgressUpdate(MarkerOptions... values) {
   maps.addMarker(values);
}
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   // or you can add all markers to maps in here
}
```

Comment: Also, add markers to map `onPostExecute`, not on the background thread

Comment: I fail to see how that fixes the IllegalStateException

Comment: Thank  Iulian Popescu so much for correct me.  
@cricket_007 I think `IllegalStateException` happend because he update UI in background thread

Comment: how  can move `maps.addMarker...` to `onPostExecute`? because the add marker have `i` from looping `for`

Comment: @E-Place It seems you can loop over `MyArrListATM`... So you can move the `maps.addMarker`

Comment: @E-Place you can call `publishProgress(markerOptions)` in a loop and do `addMarker()` in `onProgressUpdate()`

Comment: @YaroslavMytkalyk how about `i` from `addMarker` it will be error

Comment: @E-Place You shouldn't need `i` there... You can use `for (HashMap<String, String> map : MyArrListATM)` in `onPostExectute`

Answer (score 0):

You can not access to `maps` in background thread. you can use `publishProgress` and handle it in `onProgressUpdate` method.